# Same subject with different verb forms

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural

I have two sentences with two same subject 'the possession and exercise' but it has two different verbs, one is singular and other is plural.

> [Source](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=EWTiE-a_TD8C&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=%22the+possession+and+exercise+of%22&source=bl&ots=wbzWDprhx4&sig=3rvGnVQSK88EYI1fJCrQqAmnJRw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiig6W2p67NAhXEuY8KHXdzCHcQ6AEIKzAE#v=onepage&q=%22the%20possession%20and%20exercise%20of%22&f=false): The possession and exercise of the skills of archery **make** one good as an archer. (plural)
>
> [Source](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=0PzJ2sOe3YgC&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=%22the+possession+and+exercise+of%22&source=bl&ots=hfoEZGacGG&sig=Kr-2oI_j6X4r698oHRqBDhpMUFc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiig6W2p67NAhXEuY8KHXdzCHcQ6AEIMzAH#v=onepage&q=%22the%20possession%20and%20exercise%20of%22&f=false): ...the possession and exercise of virtue **is** in the best interest of the virtuous person... (singular)

It would be more helpful if anyone with different examples.

Comment: make could be singular: I make bread.

Comment: @djna - Yes, but not in this case, where the thing we're talking about is clearly third person.

Comment: @stangdon So in this criterion, what should I do?

Comment: Can we possess virtue yet not exercise it?  Can we exercise virtue yet not possess it? Is not the possession and exercise of virtue the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

When we combine two things with **and**, we sometimes treat them as one thing, and so use a verb in the singular, for example

> Fish and chips **is** still England's favorite take-home food [Restaurant business vol. 79](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=9FosAQAAMAAJ&q=%22fish%20and%20chips%20is%22&dq=%22fish%20and%20chips%20is%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y)

There is no consistency though, and you will find many sentences where **are** is used about fish and chips.

> Fish and chips **are** a highly nutritious balanced meal [Papers by command, vol6](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=tcQ5AQAAIAAJ&q=%22fish%20and%20chips%20are%22&dq=%22fish%20and%20chips%20are%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJitnu3a7NAhVHX5QKHXH8CFYQ6AEIGjAA)

Here is an [article](http://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/are-subjects-joined-by-and-singular-or-plural-grammar-rules) explaining how to tell whether the two nouns are independent (and so a verb in the plural is required) or treated as one thing (and so a verb in the singular is required).

Comment: As mentioned in your source, can you divide the sentence "the possession and exercise of virtue **is** in the best interest of the virtuous person"? If I divide the sentence, I feel it is better to use '**are**' here. Can you explain this?

Comment: @ARYF: You can say "the possession of virtue is..." and you can say "the exercise of virtue is...":  they both make sense. The two nouns are therefore independent, and so you should use **are**.

Comment: If you scrutinize the source, is that grammatical mistake?

Comment: @ARYF: According to the article I quoted, the second example should use **are**. But as TRomano asks, is it possible to possess virtue and not exercise it, or vice versa? That is a matter of opinion, so it's not a question of a *grammatical mistake*: it depends on the opinion of the writer, and maybe he wants to convey the impression that you can't have one without the other.

Comment: If you edit this source, what will be your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you connect to nouns with "and" and you consider them to be a unit, in which case the verb to use is singular.

For example: *Bread and butter is my favourite breakfast.*

I think that the person who wrote the sentence might mean that both having the skill plus exercising it blend into one requirement for somebody to be a good archer.

Comment: I am aware of what you quoted in the answer, which is the simplest form. I need in answer for complex sentences.